# how do I connect to a local server from an IPhone using safari?

Tags: javascript, server, safari, get

I have this url:

> http://192.168.1.42:8080/users

my node server detects every get request from anyone in the LAN except for my IPhone when I use safari, if i use chrome on it then it does work.

Any idea why?

*before you say that this question has already been asked and answered, no it has not been*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Chrome or if you just need it to make a request you can install

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/rest-http-api-client/id1318172341

and you'll be able to make fully customisable http requests either from the app or shortcuts, which is just what I needed.

Comment: Making custom http requests is often different than what most people mean by the phrase "connecting to a server" with a web browser... you also don't really answer your own question; providing an app link doesn't at all answer "Any idea why [it doesn't work on iPhone]?".